# Discard character in matching group

Tags: php, regex

I have a couple of matching groups one after another in a long Regex pattern. Around the middle I have

```
...(?<number>(?:/(?:digit|num))?\d+|)...
```

which should match something like `/num9`, `/digit9` or `9` or blank (because I need the named group to appear in the resulting associative array even if it's empty).

The pattern works, but is it possible to discard the `/` character if the one of first two cases is matched? I tried a positive lookahead, but it seems that you can't use those if you have expressions before the lookahead.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible using Regex?

Comment: Try a positive lookbehind and put it outside your named group.

Comment: @FailedDev Wouldn't that also match `/9`?

Comment: @Blake Yes, sorry didn't see the double `))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your input, I think that you need to capture `/` anyway at some point, otherwise your whole regex fails. At the same time you want to ignore it, so it cannot be a part of you named group. Therefore by putting it outside it and making it optional, while ensuring that a digit is not preceded directly by a `/` you come up with the desired results :

```
^/?(?<number>(?:(?:digit|num))?(?<!/)\d+|)$
```

However given your lack of a more complete input and regex, I am not 100% sure this will work for all your cases.

Comment: That's such a lovely solution. I need to start thinking outside the box ._.

Comment: @Blake You'll get the hang of it.. Just takes time :)